# How can I set Samba domain controller user as linux file owner?

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, access-control-list, samba4

I am trying to **set a user in my Samba active directory domain controller as owner of a file** on my domain controller server, I am trying exactly what I found on samba official wiki here: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Shares_with_POSIX_ACLs

```
chown "Someuser" /srv/samba/Demo/Example
chown root:"Demo Group" /srv/samba/Demo/Example
```

but that doesn't work, the system tells me that the **group or the user is invalid**. Could someone help me to **change the owner of the file or folder to be one of my DC members using the normal linux commands** like what I used above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the answer, shortly, I cannot do that with the domain controller:

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller

> Running shares with POSIX ACLs on a Samba DC is not supported. To provide network shares with the full capabilities of Samba, set up a Samba domain member with file shares.